# unable to access 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git/': Failed connect to github.com:3128; Operation timed out

Tags: ios, facebook, git, github

I tried to install `Cocoapods` `Facebook-iOS-SDK` but i am getting the following error

```
    Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.12.0)
[!] Pod::Executable remote update

Fetching origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git/': Failed connect to github.com:3128; Operation timed out

error: Could not fetch origin
```

thanks

Comment: Why don't you download it from [developer.facebook.com](https://developer.facebook.com);

Comment: platform :ios, "6.0"

pod "AFNetworking", '2.0.3'
pod "Appirater"
pod "CocoaLumberjack"
pod 'DAKeyboardControl', '~> 2.3'
pod "Facebook-iOS-SDK"
pod 'HPGrowingTextView', '~> 1.1'
pod "HockeySDK"
pod "MagicalRecord", :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'SIAlertView', :podspec => 'PodSpecs/SIAlertView.podspec'
pod "SSKeychain"
pod "UIAlertView-Blocks"
pod 'gtm-oauth2', '~> 0.0.3' while installing all these i am stuck with facebook sdk pod installation